# Creating a flow or livedata from a list stored in a Room DB entity class

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I have a class which I store in a room database. The class contains a mutable list where elements are added and removed from time to time. Now I want to observe the changes of the content of the list in the UI, for example I want to show the size of the array in a TextView. Below is an example class. How can I do this?

```kotlin
class MyClass(
    @PrimaryKey var id: Long = 0L,
    var myList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
) : Serializable {

    fun addElement(value: Int) { myList.add(value) }
}
```

Changing `myList` to an observable (LiveData/StateFlow) won't work, because the list itself remains the same and only the content changes.
I could start a coroutine that checks every n ms if the list has changed and update the value, but this would be very bad code.

I could add a variable that gets manually updated when the list gets updated, e.g.

```kotlin
private val _arraySize: MutableStateFlow<Int> = MutableStateFlow(myList.size)
val arraySize: StateFlow<Int>
    get() = _arraySize

fun addElement(value: Int) {
    myList.add(value)
    _arraySize.value = myList.size
}
```

But this blows up the class and I have to `@Ignore` all the Flows so they do not get stored in the DB, especially if I want e.g. not only size but also maximum, minimum, and other values calculated from the array.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: How do you retrieve the `MyClass` object from the database? There's definitely a DAO for this. You can just use Kotlin Flows to retrieve `MyCalss` and when there is any changes to the data base it will emits those changes automatically.

Comment: There is a DAO for the object in the database but the changes to `myList` are only written to the DB after the user confirms the changes. Meanwhile the changes to `myList` should update the view immediately.

Comment: You should update it in the database. Room will take care of propagating the change.